# mock testing paypal checkout with cucumber

Tags: ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, cucumber

How can I use cucumber and simulating a redirect to paypal and back?

I developed a web application where you can do paypal payments and I want to create a test to my functionality using cucumber, but I am stuck with the paypal redirect issue to test my web app.

Using

- cucumber 1.3.16
- cucumber-rails 1.4.1
- rails 4
- paypal-recurring

## result

Feature: Subscribe service

So that user can subscribe to any service

As a user

I want to add a service to user account

Scenario: subscribe to service "Monthly bill" correctly                                         # features/subscribe_service.feature:7

```
Given a user go to "url" and click "sign in"                                              # features/step_definitions/create_account_steps.rb:2

And username and password: "user@example.com", "password"                                                   # features/step_definitions/login_account_steps.rb:2

And a plan "Monthly bill "                                                                     # features/step_definitions/subscribe_service_steps.rb:1

When a Customer login into the account with a email and passwd: "user@example.com", "password"              # features/step_definitions/login_account_steps.rb:6

Then I should see plan "Monthly bill"                                                         # features/step_definitions/subscribe_service_steps.rb:5

 And a user click into "Subscribe"                                                                           # features/step_definitions/update_account_password_steps.rb:1

 Then go to click pay for subscribe                                                                          # features/step_definitions/subscribe_service_steps.rb:9
  **No route matches [GET] "/cgi-bin/webscr" (ActionController::RoutingError)**
  ./features/step_definitions/subscribe_service_steps.rb:11:in `/^go to click pay for subscribe$/'
```

## features/subscribe_service.feature:14:in `Then go to click pay for subscribe'

There any way to mock the paypal payment and return back with a result to the application?

Answer (score 0):

Ok to fix the issue above I impLemented this step, **but now I got another error**, it seems like the redirect from paypal simulation is logout the user, as result now whe it try to complete the payment, its redirect to the login page. this is using webmock.

```
Given(/^paypal will authorize payment$/) do
  # Because paypal_recurring will redirect the client                                                                                                        \

  # to the http://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr                                                                                                          \

  # We need to define this route to prevent the "undefined route"                                                                                            \


  Rails.application.routes.append do
    get '/cgi-bin/webscr' => "stores#subscription"
  end

  Rails.application.reload_routes!

      stub_request(:post, "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp").
       to_return(:status => 200, :body => " ", :headers => {})

end
```

cucumber log

```
  Scenario: subscribe to service "Monthly bill" correctly                                         # features/subscribe_service.feature:7
    Given a user go to "http://localhost:3000" and click "sign in"                                              # features/step_definitions/create_account_steps.rb:2
    And username and password: "user@example.com", "password"                                                   # features/step_definitions/login_account_steps.rb:2
    And a plan "Monthly bill "                                                                     # features/step_definitions/subscribe_service_steps.rb:1
    And paypal will authorize payment                                                                           # features/step_definitions/subscribe_service_steps.rb:5
    When a Customer login into the account with a email and passwd: "user@example.com", "password"              # features/step_definitions/login_account_steps.rb:6
    Then I should see plan "Monthly bill "                                                         # features/step_definitions/subscribe_service_steps.rb:25
    And a user click into "Subscribe"                                                                           # features/step_definitions/update_account_password_steps.rb:1
    Then go to click pay for subscribe                                                                          # features/step_definitions/subscribe_service_steps.rb:29
    Then go to account home with a successfull message "service added"                                          # features/step_definitions/create_account_steps.rb:23
      expected to find text "service added" in "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing. " (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/create_account_steps.rb:24:in `/^go to account home with a successfull message "(.*?)"$/'
      features/subscribe_service.feature:19:in `Then go to account home with a successfull message "service added"'
    When I open the email                                                                                       # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:76
    Then I should see "We wanted to let you know that your now are subscribe to the service." in the email body # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:108
```